# BLTouch error Marlin 2.x (on SKR 1.3)

Tags: marlin, firmware, bed-leveling, bltouch

I have some issue with my BLTouch (I'm new to bed levelling) :
I compiled Marlin 2.x (for my SKR 1.3) for a Antclabs BLTouch, and everytime I power on the printer, it shows this error message: `Failed to enable Bed Leveling, echo Bed Levelling off, echo : Fade Height 0, FF, ok`:

[image: BLTouch error message on LCD display]

The LED of the BLTouch is on, I can still deploy and stow the pin, and do "levelling ABL" but Homing Z (for example) is not working.
I linked the config.h and config_adv.h in case needed below:

- [Configuration.h](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/493040686564638735/687094545774936064/Configuration.h)
- [Configuration_adv.h](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/493040686564638735/687094551256760341/Configuration_adv.h)

Comment: I have potentially find the problem, need time to confirm, and I'll write here, but thanks

Comment: it's fixed : it's because I didn't level the bed once after flashing the firmware, once it has been done the error is no more

Answer (score 2):

From [a comment](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/12159/bltouch-error-marlin-2-x-on-skr-1-3#comment22355_12159) can be read that the OP found the solution:

> it's fixed : it's because I didn't level the bed once after flashing the firmware, once it has been done the error is no more

Comment: How did you level the bed? Each time I press home, my print head goes all the way to the end rail and try to keep going until I turn off the power.

Comment: @MarcusMiles Please post your own question, it will attract attention and possibly answers, it will not receive answers here in comments. Please take the [tour] and read [help] how SE sites work, we're not regular discussion forums, instead it's a simple Q and A format.